# Could not find ffi in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler, ffi

On OS X 10.9.5...

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.4'
gem 'uglifier', '2.7.2'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'turbolinks', '2.5.3'
gem 'jbuilder', '2.3.1'
gem 'sdoc', '0.4.1', group: :doc
gem 'mongoid', '4.0.2'
gem 'mongoid-grid_fs', '2.1.0'
gem 'watir-rails', '1.1.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', '6.0.2'
  gem 'web-console', '2.2.1'
  gem 'spring', '1.3.6'
end
```

**Terminal**

```
$ bundle install
...
Installing ffi 1.9.10 with native extensions
...
Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 68 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
$ bundle show ffi
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/ffi-1.9.10
$ rails c
Could not find ffi-1.9.10 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems
```

I tried placing "gem 'ffi', '1.9.10'" in my Gemfile.

I tried removing my Gemfile.lock and repeating this process.

I tried `bundle exec rails c`.

I tried `gem install ffi --version 1.0.11`, which seems to be the dependency for childprocess-0.5.6.

None of these attempts make any difference. Any ideas?

Comment: My app is still quite simple so I created a new one with all of the same code and I no longer have this problem. I would still love to know what causes this or how to resolve it. In the future it may not be feasible to re-create the app.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this same error just now, solved with `gem pristine --all`

Comment: I tried this but got "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory."

Comment: @MasonBallowe try this "sudo gem pristine --all"

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue with

```
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.10.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.10.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.
```

A `bundle update` followed by a `bundle install` solved it for me